# Means and Set of Rational Numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

Let $S$ be the set $\{0, 1\}$. Given any subset of $S$ we may add its arithmetic mean to $S$ (provided it is not already included - $S$ never includes duplicates). Show that by repeating this process we can include the number $1/5$ in $S$. Show that we can eventually include any rational number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: OK, what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a cool question! OP should definitely detail what they've already tried though.

> **Lemma**
>
> If we can make $x$ and $y$ then we can make $x+\frac{k}{2^n}(y-x)$ for all $k\leq 2^n$.

Proof: for $n=1$, this is clearly true.
Suppose it is true for $n=t$. Then for $n=t+1$, note that if $k$ is even then it reduces to the case for $t$, otherwise $$x+\frac{k}{2^{t+1}}(y-x)=\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\left(x+\frac{\frac{1}{2}(k-1)}{2^t}(y-x)\right)+\left(x+\frac{\frac{1}{2}(k+1)}{2^t}(y-x)\right)\right)$$ so by induction the lemma is true.

> **Lemma**
>
> If we can make $x$ and $y$ then we can make $x+(y-x)\frac{1}{n}$.

Proof: let $f(t)=x+t(y-x)$. Consider $f(\frac{1}{2}),f(\frac{1}{4}),\ldots,f(\frac{1}{2^{n-3}}),f(\frac{1}{2^{n-2}})$ (all makeable by lemma $1$) and add two "weird" terms $f(\frac{1}{2^{n}}),f(\frac{3}{2^{n}})$. Note that there are $n$ terms here, so the sum is $nx+(y-x)$ and thus their average is $x+\frac{1}{n}(y-x)$

Finally, to make $\frac{a}{b}$ we iterate lemma 2:

We can make $\frac{1}{b},\frac{2}{b},\frac{3}{b},\ldots,\frac{a}{b}$ by repeated using lemma 2 with $n=b,b-1,b-2,\ldots$.

And just for fun, an explicit construction for $\frac{1}{5}$:

$$0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{32}$$

are all quite easy to make; each is the average of the last one and $0$. Now $\frac{3}{32}$ is the average of $\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16}$. Finally, $$1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{3}{32}$$ so if you take their average you get $\frac{1}{5}$.